# pulseview doesn't run (undefined symbol)

Tags: command-line, apt, software-installation

Having a Hantek 6022be i wanted to install sigrok and pulseview.

Followed every instruction on [here](https://sigrok.org/wiki/Linux#Building_.28script.2C_recommended.29) to build and install libserialport, libsigrok, libsigrokdecode, sigrok-cli and pulseview and [here](https://sigrok.org/wiki/Fx2lafw#Build_sigrok) to install fx2lafw.

After install, since no app icon is available, by running

```
pulseview
```

terminal says it can't find command, so i installed by apt

```
sudo apt install pulseview
```

after installing by apt i now have the pulseview icon on the applications window but nothing happens on click, by running pulseview from terminal i get

```
pulseview: symbol lookup error: pulseview: undefined symbol: _ZN6sigrok7Context20create_analog_packetESt6vectorISt10shared_ptrINS_7ChannelEESaIS4_EEPfjPKNS_8QuantityEPKNS_4UnitES1_IPKNS_12QuantityFlagESaISG_EE
```

sigrok-cli works and finds the oscilloscope

```
sigrok-cli --scan

The following devices were found:
demo - Demo device with 13 channels: D0 D1 D2 D3 D4 D5 D6 D7 A0 A1 A2 A3 A4
fx2lafw:conn=1.11 - Saleae Logic [S/N: Saleae Logic] with 8 channels: D0 D1 D2 D3 D4 D5 D6 D7
```

I'm using ubuntu 20.04

```
lsb_release -a

No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04 LTS
Release:    20.04
Codename:   focal
```

Been searching everywhere for the last couple hours for a solution, but found nothing.

Maybe i screwd up by installing from source and then by apt? but sigrok-cli suffered the same procedure and survived...

after all this, i don't even know how to uninstall what i just installed...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the error you're getting is because the PulseView you installed using apt is incompatible with the libsigrokcxx.so that you have installed. sigrok-cli doesn't use it, so it doesn't complain.

Generally, we don't recommend building from source if all you want is the latest build. If that's all you want, use the AppImage: https://sigrok.org/wiki/Downloads#Linux_AppImage_binaries

Comment: I am using the AppImage from here https://sigrok.org/wiki/Downloads

and yet I'm still having the same error.


```
pulseview: /tmp/.mount_PulseVkiAlgV/usr/lib/libselinux.so.1: no version information available (required by /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgio-2.0.so.0)
pulseview: /tmp/.mount_PulseVkiAlgV/usr/lib/libselinux.so.1: no version information available (required by /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmount.so.1)
pulseview: symbol lookup error: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgio-2.0.so.0: undefined symbol: g_module_open_full

```

Comment: Yes me too.. I can't use the AppImage either.. Help!